# Tokudb file space low error

Tags: tokumx

I have my mongo data files in a temporary directory.
I start the server by giving :
    ./mongod --dbpath /nlu/users/ig/mongodb
It was working fine and i could write into the db using a python driver.  I get this error today.
Please help on how to solve.

Also how to set tokudb_fs_reserve_percent?
Thanks!

```
bash-3.2$ ./mongod --dbpath /nlu/users/ig/tokudata 
Mon Jul 15 18:22:28  nssize is a deprecated parameter  
Mon Jul 15 18:22:28 [initandlisten] TokuMX starting : pid=9880 port=27017               dbpath=/nlu/users/indrani_gorti/tokudata 64-bit host=unv-ig
Mon Jul 15 18:22:28 [initandlisten] TokuMX mongod server v1.0.1-mongodb-2.2.4, using TokuKV rev 8f8d303
Mon Jul 15 18:22:28 [initandlisten] git version: 101a2f8
Mon Jul 15 18:22:28 [initandlisten] build info: Linux lex1.tokutek.com 2.6.18-    308.8.2.el5 #1 SMP Tue Jun 12 09:58:12 EDT 2012 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
Mon Jul 15 18:22:28 [initandlisten] options: { dbpath: "/nlu/users/indrani_gorti/tokudata" }  
Mon Jul 15 18:22:29 [initandlisten] [tokumx] startup
Mon Jul 15 18:22:29 [initandlisten] [tokumx] locktree max memory set to 418906316 bytes.
Mon Jul 15 18:22:32 2013 Tokudb file system space is low
Mon Jul 15 18:22:32 [initandlisten] ERROR: listen(): bind() failed errno:98 Address already in use for socket: 0.0.0.0:27017
Mon Jul 15 18:22:32 [initandlisten] ERROR:   addr already in use
Mon Jul 15 18:22:32 [initandlisten] now exiting
Mon Jul 15 18:22:32 dbexit:
Mon Jul 15 18:22:32 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
Mon Jul 15 18:22:32 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
Mon Jul 15 18:22:32 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
Mon Jul 15 18:22:32 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close databases...
Mon Jul 15 18:22:32 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to shutdown TokuKV...
Mon Jul 15 18:22:32 [initandlisten] [tokumx] shutdown
Mon Jul 15 18:22:32 [TTLMonitor] ERROR: Client::shutdown not called: TTLMonitor
Mon Jul 15 18:22:32 [websvr] ERROR: listen(): bind() failed errno:98 Address already in use for socket: 0.0.0.0:28017
Mon Jul 15 18:22:32 [websvr] ERROR:   addr already in use
Mon Jul 15 18:22:33 [initandlisten] shutdown: removing fs lock...
Mon Jul 15 18:22:33 dbexit: really exiting now
```

Answer (score 1):

The fatal error here is this:

```
Mon Jul 15 18:22:32 [initandlisten] ERROR: listen(): bind() failed errno:98 Address already in use for socket: 0.0.0.0:27017
Mon Jul 15 18:22:32 [initandlisten] ERROR:   addr already in use
```

This indicates that you already have another mongod running on port 27017.  You need to either use the other mongod process that's running, shut it down before starting this one, or use a different port for this mongod process.

In TokuMX, the setting you're looking for is called `--fsRedzone`, rather than `tokudb_fs_reserve_percent`.